# CountIF and Sum Formula in Excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to write a formula to search the person's name and then show a result that out of 3 fruits how many times that person has purchased Apples, Oranges and Mangos. The fruits are constant and cannot change; however, there could be more than one person in the list who can buy these fruits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to let Excel do all the heavy lifting.  Pivot tables are a wizard to make summarizing data simple.

[image]

You highlight the data and select `Insert` | `Pivot Table` from the menu.  I'm using LibreOffice Calc, so the dialog window looks slightly different, but the steps are essentially the same.

[image]

You click and drag `Person` from the `Available Fields` to the `Row Fields` box, Click and drag `Fruit` from the `Available Fields` to the `Column Fields` box.  And click and drag it again to the `Data Fields` box.  There, you have a choice of how to aggregate the values.  If Excel's default aggregation isn't `Count`, double click on it and select `Count`.

You can select where you want to stick the table and there's an option to skip row and column summaries.  Click OK and you're done.

Comment: Upvote for PivotTables.  Once you learn them, tasks like this become very straightforward.